# Utterance (customDimensions['Text']) is not reported in app insights in Azure Chatbot

Tags: azure, chatbot, azure-application-insights

I'm using Azure's Chatbot Service to build the chatbot. For data collection, I'm also using Azure Monitor to track and get the data of the conversation from the chatbot and users. The target is to retain the way we captured utterances in ***customDimensions ['Text']***. However, I can't find the attribute "['Text']" in ***customDimensions***.

Could someone know how I can get around this?

Thank you.

Comment: [Utterance (customDimensions 'Text' ) is not reported in app insights inhibiting conversation analytics](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/7533)

Answer (score 0):

> Utterance (customDimensions['Text']) is not reported in app insights
> in Azure Chatbot

Please follow below ***reference*** it has detail explanation about:

- Schema of Bot Analytics Instrumentation
- Custom Dimensions SDK Bot Analytics
- Enabling telemetry to capture usage data from other services like LUIS and QnA Maker

**Reference:**

[Analyze the telemetry data from your bot - Bot Service | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry-analytics-queries?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#schema-of-bot-analytics-instrumentation)

[Enabling telemetry to capture usage data from other services like LUIS and QnA Maker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-telemetry?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp#enabling-telemetry-to-capture-usage-data-from-other-services-like-luis-and-qna-maker)